# Passar dados sem parsing para o handlebars

Tags: javascript, json, handlebars.js

Eu estou a passar dados para o handlebars através do express assim:

```
res.render('user/apps/todos', { todos: JSON.stringify(todos) });`
```

E recebo assim na página:

```
{{ todos }}
```

Agora, se `todos` for:

```
[{"title":"My first todo","body":"My first todo's body"},{"title":"My first todo 3","body":"My first todo's body 3"},{"title":"SAD","body":"INSANE AMOUNTS OF SADNESS\n3"}]
```

O handlebars converte-me para:

```
[{&quot;title&quot;:&quot;My first todo&quot;,&quot;body&quot;:&quot;My first todo&#x27;s body&quot;},{&quot;title&quot;:&quot;My first todo 3&quot;,&quot;body&quot;:&quot;My first todo&#x27;s body 3&quot;},{&quot;title&quot;:&quot;SAD&quot;,&quot;body&quot;:&quot;INSANE AMOUNTS OF SADNESS\n3&quot;}]
```

Como impedir o handlebars de fazer esta operação?

Comment: Experimenta utilizar desta forma:
res.render('user/apps/todos', { todos: todos });

Comment: Testa somente com `res.render('user/apps/todos', {todos});`, não precisas do `JSON.stringify`

Comment: @ApoloMaster Preciso, caso contrário recebo [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: Se colocares `{{ todos }}` aparece ` [object Object]`... faz sentido. Mas dentro desse todos queres mostrar só partes certo? podes dar um exemplo do HTML que esperas obter?

Comment: @Sergio eu queria obter o que forneci na função render, que é o array todos

Comment: Sim, mas queres mostrar o array "cru" ou iterar os dados e criar HTML com isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, ao que parece a prop "todos" engloba todos os dados e você quer renderizá-los de uma única vez, para isso deverá utilizar um iterador, o handlebars oferece algumas props auxiliares, veja:

- Primeiro você deve passar o "todos" como um array:

  ```
  const todos = [{"title":"My first todo","body":"My first todo's body"},{"title":"My first todo 3","body":"My first todo's body 3"},{"title":"SAD","body":"INSANE AMOUNTS OF SADNESS\n3"}];

  res.render('user/apps/todos', { todos });
  ```
- Em seguida remonte o seu template da seguinte maneira:

  ```
  {{#each todos}}
  <div class='todo'>
      <div>{{title}}</div>
      <div>{{body}}</div>
  </div>
  {{/each}}
  ```
- Protótipo de como deve funcionar:

```js
const todos = [{title:"My first todo", body:"My first todo's body"},{title:"My first todo 3", body:"My first todo's body 3"},{title:"SAD", body:"INSANE AMOUNTS OF SADNESS 3"}];

const render = document.querySelector('#render');
const template = render.innerHTML.replace(/\n*/g, '');

const each = template.match(/{{#each \w+}}.*{{\/each}}/gi).join('');

const eachStart = each.indexOf('}}', 8) + 2;
const eachEnd = each.lastIndexOf('{{');

const content = each.substring(eachStart, eachEnd).replace(/\s{2}/g, '');

render.innerHTML = '';

todos.forEach(todo => {
  render.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', content.replace('{{title}}', todo.title).replace('{{body}}', todo.body));
});
```

```css
* {
  font: 15px monospace, sans-serif
}

.title {
  color: #fff;
  background: #555;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 2.5px #000;
}

.body {
  color: #000;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 5px #000;
}
```

```html
<!-- OBS: A div render foi somente para componentizar o temmplate! -->
<div id="render">
  {{#each todos}}
    <div class="container">
      <div class="title">{{title}}</div>
      <div class="body">{{body}}</div>
    </div>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

Comment: estive a pesquisar mais e encontrei uma maneira mais simples que é usar {{{ todos }}} em vez de {{ todos }}, mas qual é a diferença entre as duas situações? É só que uma faz parsing e a outra não?